# Core Data Create Entity from Interface Elements

Tags: macos, core-data, view, xcode4, interface

I am new to Xcode and OS X app development.

I want to create a small app to manage local passwords.  Basically this app will consist of a Core Data entity for Password that has tags label, and value attributes.  I want the interface to simply be a search field that searches tags and displays the first result's label:password in a field under the search box.  Under the search result field, I would like 3 text fields and an add button.  You fill out the text fields like an HTML form and click add.  This adds a new Password to the data store using the fields as the values for the new entity and then clears the fields.

Any example code or tutorials would be great.  I have already read several tutorials about using a TableView and an add button that adds a blank entity and then you select that and edit it via bound text fields but this is not quite what I want.  I want to be able to specify the new entity attribute values before clicking add.

Comment: Storing passwords in a Core Data store is incredibly insecure. The keychain exists for this reason and is a handy place to store secured data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is make the needed textfield, let the user fill them, and after that, let him press that "add" button.

If you understand, how it works, all that's left for you is add the attributes for the entity you create—just get them from the textfields, like

```
entity.firstAttr = texfield1.text;,etc
```

Than save the context and here you are!

**EDIT**
That's how you add the action

```
[checkIfAlright addTarget:yourButton action:@selector(yourMethod)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

That's how you save the context

```
 NSError *error = nil;
[context save:&error];
```

Comment: I figured it was something like that, but the problem is I am new to OSX development and so I don't know how attach functions to the click event of a button or how to programmatically save an entity.  Any tutorials or example code for that would be perfect.

Comment: i ended up with something quite similar.  Just created outlets for the textfields, attached an action to the add button and search field.